# Infer typescript generic wrapper function return type property value

Tags: typescript

How to properly infer `xxx` type to `data`?

Restrictions:

- wrapper argument should accept only `Promise<{ xxx: Data; }>` - currently works.
- only wrapper can be changed

[Typescript sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAdwE4EMAOmCmqA8AsAFCJmIAi6U6ANCeYgIKI4AeUOYAJgM6IAFVHAC2MXjnwBvRGzkAuStXQBuRAF8AfPVLlNACnSKmASkVDR4yTO7LFVGhs2IpDcqhxQQqJAEZE6PzoYACeJOokkcSBIZCIoJCwCAH6ZoLCYhLSsgqIvFCoMGAA5k4ubmQeXj4uOWyKAOToDRrhUSRoWLiohqkmAHRQABZc+h78ALzOrrpkEAj5iLY0ivmFJYgTiOP9y+iIAPQHiOKI4ADWYHDIYLSIQ9eIUHCIIujnOCdQJ2DAeHkFIrFAD84RMQA)

```
function wrapper<
    Data,
    A extends Promise<{ xxx: Data; }>,
    >(a: A): Promise<{ data: Data }> {
    return 1 as any
}


async function a(): Promise<{ xxx: string }> {
    return { xxx: 'a' }
}


wrapper(a()).then(res => {
    const data: string = res.data // is unknown, how to make it infer string?
})
```

Comment: Generic constraints don't serve as inference sites for type parameters; so `Data` cannot be inferred from `A extends Promise<{xxx: Data}>`.  Such behavior was suggested in [ms/TS#7234](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234) but never implemented.  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wOPgzN) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: did you answer me?  I thought I got a comment notification but it seems to be gone now.

Comment: @jcalz yes, it meets my needs, please answer so that I could accept it. Not sure why it was deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you expect the compiler to infer `A` as `Promise<{ xxx: string }>`, and from there to infer `Data` as `string` because `A extends Promise<{xxx: Data}>`.  Unfortunately, in TypeScript, [generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) like `extends Promise<{xxx: Data}>` don't serve as inference sites for type parameters.  (Such behavior was suggested in [microsoft/TypeScript#7234](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234) but was never implemented.)  So the compiler has no idea what to infer `Data` as, and thus it falls back to [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown).  Oops.

In order to get inference for `Data` (which I will rename to `D` to be more in keeping with the usual naming conventions for type parameters) from `a`, you'll need to give `a` a type which is directly related to `D`.  Here's the easiest way to do it:

```
function wrapper<D>(a: Promise<{xxx: D}>): Promise<{ data: D }> {
    return 1 as any
}
```

You weren't really using `A` in your code, so I left it out.  Instead, we say that `a` is of type `Promise<{xxx: D}>`.  The compiler *can* infer `D` from that, by matching `Promise<{xxx: string}>` to `Promise<{xxx: D}>`.

Let's see it in action:

```
wrapper(a()).then(res => {
    const data: string = res.data // okay
});
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAdwE4EMAOmCmqA8AIgHwAU6AXIgAqpwC2MAzjvgN4AeXVhAvsQEoqtBs1ZtEAE3RRKiQon6I2AWABQiTYlQ4oIVEgCMidExNgAnut7rba0xciJQkWAhOkhNOoxbtEXBxUTFCoMGAA5orEyupa2rr6SBKBVADk6GmK1nbqaFi4qOSeAgB0UAAWOGCkOmYAvDGqGloQCCFSMnIhYZGI9QlMpdKyiAD0Y4hwANboVmq8AkA)